# Tackling large spring integration xml files

Tags: spring, integration

How can a large Spring integration xml file be effectively managed? Any specific best practices for reducing the complexity? (reuse/chaining possible ?)

How effective is spring-integration-flow in reducing the complexity of integration xml?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link for multiple Spring Integration files effectively. You can divide the many config files.

"https://www.mkyong.com/spring/load-multiple-spring-bean-configuration-file/"

Comment: how to split an spring integration file (not DI configuration) that is huge? each steps are connected with another. is there a way by which it can be managed ?